# Check each value of an enum is in at most one element of a list using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Given `MyEnum`, class `MyClass` with property `EnumValue` and `IList<MyClass> list` is there a clever LINQ way to determine no enum value is found in more than one list element, without writing a loop?

A little code-golfy I know but it's a real-world bit of code I'm writing and I wondered if it is possible in a non-horrific fashion?

For example:

```
foreach (var e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)))
                Assert.IsTrue(list.Count(x => x.EnumValue == e) <= 1);
```

Comment: When you say "without using a loop" - do you mean "without using a loop in your code"? It won't be possible without a loop executing somewhere. Note that it would be easier to understand the question if you demonstrated it with a [mcve] rather than just describing it.

Comment: I cannot understand this part: "no enum value is found in more than one list element"

Comment: @JonSkeet I think without _writing_ a loop is probably implied but I added a clarifying example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to check if `MyEnum` values in `list` objects appears at most once, you can group the items in `list` by `EnumValue` property value and check how many items are on those groups:

```
bool result = list.GroupBy(c => c.EnumValue).All(g => g.Count() == 1);
```

Comment: You can also check if it is equal to 1. It can never be less than 1.

Comment: @YacoubMassad: absolutely true.